# Can't get tensorflow to build a model which will even match a very simple linear graph

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I can't seem to get tensorflow to build a model which matches even the simplest linear graph.
Below is the code and the actual vs the model results. 
What am I doing wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras

x = np.array([[1965.0], [1980.0]])
y = np.array([[320.0], [345.0]])

plt.plot(x, y)
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=10000)


yHat = model.predict(x)
print("yHat ", yHat)
plt.plot(x, yHat)
plt.show()
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Maybe if you try to standardize your data it will learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, just missing some key points when normalizing your data and building your model.

1. There are only 2 data points being fed into your neural network. Use `np.arange()` instead to create a larger array.
2. Neural networks like data points between 0 and 1 (helps with learning convergence). So let's transform the x and y arrays using sklearn.MinMaxScaler :
   *(this will transform each variable between 0 and 1 based on its value to the min and max values of the array)*

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler  
scaler = MinMaxScaler()  
x = scaler.fit_transform(np.arange(1965, 1990).reshape(-1,1))  
y = scaler.fit_transform(np.arange(320, 345).reshape(-1,1))
```

(note: we're reshaping x,y to fit a (1,0) numpy array)

4. Then we can build the model using 1 linear Dense layer:

```
epochs = 20
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense( units=1, input_dim=1, activation="linear" ))

## Establishing optimizer so that we can modify the learning rate >= 1
sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile( optimizer=sgd, loss="mean_squared_error" )
model.fit( x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=epochs)
```

4. Lastly we can plot the predicted and actual Y variables:

```
predicted = model.predict(x)
predicted = predicted + .01 ## offset prediction so the two lines don't overlap

plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(y), label='actual_y')
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(predicted), label='predicted_y')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

*(Note: we're reversing the sklearn.tranform to show the actual data instead of the Scaled version)*

Final code all together:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.layers.core import Dense

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

epochs = 20

## Using np.arange() instead of np.array()
## Transforming x,y so that the model can understand the variables
x = scaler.fit_transform(np.arange(1965, 1990).reshape(-1,1))
y = scaler.fit_transform(np.arange(320, 345).reshape(-1,1))

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense( units=1, input_dim=1, activation="linear" ))

## Establishing optimizer so that we can modify the learning rate >= 1
sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile( optimizer=sgd, loss="mean_squared_error" )
model.fit( x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=epochs)

predicted = model.predict(x)
predicted = predicted + .01 ## offset prediction so the two lines don't overlap

plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(y), label='actual_y')
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(predicted), label='predicted_y')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked perfectly when I scaled them. Why is this?

Comment: For the reasons mentioned. 1. You need A LOT more data when training a neural network. 2. Scaling helps your neural network learn. Think about it in terms of 0 and 1s. There is a lot less variability between 0 and 1 than 0 and 2000. It simply normalizes the data for your network to learn from. Normalization is a very big part of developing an accurate neural network